# Euro symbol doesn't display in dompdf generated pdf

Tags: linux, utf-8, fonts, dompdf

I'm using the [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) library to generate a pdf. I need to output an euro symbol (€) but it shows just a square. I tried using both directly the symbol or the code € and I'm using the font family like this:

```
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica", Arial, "Liberation Sans", sans-serif;
```

And I put this in the :

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

It is working fine on a Mac, but not on Linux.

Comment: It would help to know a) what version of dompdf you are using, and b) the specific code you used for the euro.

Comment: I am facing similar issue..  PDF is generated on My MAC. It is not generated on windows or Centos.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your font family dompdf will use Helvetica as the font for the text in question. Currently dompdf (up to v0.6.0) only supports Windows ANSI encoding for the core PDF fonts (of which Helvetica is one). In Windows ANSI the euro symbol is at position 128, so you might try €. This is most relevant for v0.5.1 which does not handle characters outside the Windows ANSI character set very well.

Starting in v0.6.0 dompdf works natively using UTF8. It also does a lot more work to ensure that character encoding is handled carefully. This is particularly important to avoid problems when moving from one character set to another, such as from the internal UTF8 encoding to Windows ANSI for the core PDF fonts.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of dompdf and I am trying with the symbol € and the code with ampersand (& euro;)

Comment: That works for me, even without specifying a document encoding. Do you have the MBString extension enabled? I don't have a way to test against that right now but not having it could cause character encoding issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the € symbol with

```
&#0128;  &euro;  &#8364;
```